# Parse String content to Binary and Then Convert to String in Java

Tags: java, string, utf-8, encode

I need to parse String content as binary sequence and convert them to its **UTF-8** equivalent String.

For example, **UTF-8** binary equivalents of **B**, **A** and **R** are as follows:
 
        **B = 01000010 
A = 01000001 
R = 01010010**

Now, I need to convert a string **"010000100100000101010010"** to string **"BAR"**

**i.e.** For above case input string with 24 characters are divided into three equal parts(8 character in each part) and translated to its **UTF-8** equivalent as a String value.

Sample Code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String B = "01000010";
    String A = "01000001";
    String R = "01010010";
    String BAR = "010000100100000101010010";

    String utfEquiv = toUTF8(BAR);//expecting to get "BAR"
    System.out.println(utfEquiv);
}

private static String toUTF8(String str) {
    // TODO 
    return "";
}
```

What should be the implementation of method **toUTF8(String str){}**

Comment: This might help http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Yesyoor , Updated but you can propose or EDIT. Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should separate this into two problems:

- Converting the string into a byte array by parsing the binary values
- Converting the byte array back into a string using UTF-8

The latter is very straightforward, using `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

For the first part, the tricky part is that `Byte.parseByte` won't automatically handle a leading 1... so I'd probably parse each 8-bit string into a `short` and then cast to `byte`:

```
public static byte[] binaryToBytes(String input) {
    // TODO: Argument validation (nullity, length)
    byte[] ret = new byte[input.length() / 8];
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
        String chunk = input.substring(i * 8, i * 8 + 8);
        ret[i] = (byte) Short.parseShort(chunk, 2);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: is it ``input.length`` or ``input.length()`` and ``Short.parse(chunk, 2)`` or ``Short.parseShort(chunk, 2)``? because your code showing compilation error.

Comment: @mmuzahid: Thanks for the substring fix, too. I always forget which way round Java is - .NET takes the length instead of the end index...

Comment: could you tell me the purpose of radix? I never use this.

Comment: @mmuzahid: It's to say that it's binary ('1' and '0' characters). If your string contained hex instead, it would be 16 (and you'd use two characters per byte, of course).

Comment: Striked again by Jon Skeet!